# How to update a list in Flutter with Bloc/Cubit?

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

my UI consists of a table of objects **Apples**.
Every cell in the table:

- has an **ADD** button, if the apple is NOT present for that cell
- it shows the apple and has a **DELETE** button, if the apple is present

The main page of my application is calling the following widget to **LOAD the LIST** of apples from an **API**. And also the **ADD** and **DELETE** functions communicate with the same **API** for adding and deleting the apple.

```
class ApplesLoader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ApplesLoaderState createState() => _ApplesLoaderState();
}

class _ApplesLoaderState extends State<ApplesLoader> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BlocProvider.of<ApplesCubit>(context).getAll();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<ApplesCubit, ApplesState>(
      listener: ...,
      builder: (ctx, state) {
        if (!(state is ApplesLoaded)) {
          return circularProgressIndicator;
        }
        return ApplesViewer(state.Apples);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

So after that ApplesViewerhas the list of apples and can correctly display the grid.

But now I have two problems:

1. When I press the ADD button or the DELETE button, all the application is rebuilt, while I could actually just re-paint the cell. But I don't know how to avoid this, because I also need to communicate to the application that the list of apples is actually changed. I don't want to rebuild the entire UI because it seems inefficient since what is actually changing on my page is only the selected cell.
2. When I press the ADD button or the DELETE button, I would like to show a circular progress indicator that replaces the button (while waiting for the API to actually creating/deleting the apple). But when the list changes, all the application is rebuilt instead. So, I am not sure how to achieve this desired behavior.

**Could you help me in solving those two issues?

Or advise me for a change of infrastructure in case I am making some mistake in dealing with this?**

If needed, this is the code for **ApplesCubit**

```
class ApplesCubit extends Cubit<ApplesState> {
  final ApplesRepository _repository;

  ApplesCubit(this._repository) : super(ApplesLoading());

  Future<void> getAll() async {
    try {
      final apples = await _repository.getAll();
      emit(ApplesLoaded(List<Apple>.from(apples)));
    } on DataError catch (e) {
      emit(ApplesError(e));
    }
  }

  Future<void> create(List<Apple> apples, Apple appleToAdd) async {
    try {
      final newApple = await _repository.create(appleToAdd);
      final updatedApples = List<Apple>.from(apples)..add(newApple);
      emit(ApplesLoaded(updatedApples));
    } on DataError catch (e) {
      emit(ApplesError(e));
    }
  }

  Future<void> delete(List<Apple> Appless, Apple appleToDelete) async {
    try {
      await _repository.deleteApples(appleToDelete);
      final updatedApples = List<Apple>.from(Appless)..remove(appleToDelete);
      emit(ApplesLoaded(updatedApples));
    } on DataError catch (e) {
      emit(ApplesError(e));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more context why you don't want to rebuilt the UI and why you want a progress indicator? Since adding a and removing from a list should be instant, it does not make any sense. If for some reason it is *not* instant, it would be good to know where the waiting occurs to suggest a solution.

Comment: Do you think is it clear enough now @nvoigt? Do you have some tips on how to improve the question, even more, it seems no one it is replying to it.

Comment: The fact that u should use copyWith as below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259281/2473719

Comment: @FedericoConte is this question still valid because I implemented a lot of such lists but writing the answers down takes some effort ;)